# Problems with redirecting in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have problems with my .htaccess redirecting visitors to https://palabi.net. All requests with www and/or http should be redirected to this url. I have the same setup on another domain (without the `FilesMatch` and it works perfect. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

This is my .htaccess-setup:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # No WWW
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.palabi\.net$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://palabi.net/$1 [L,R=301]


    # Force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is mod-rewrite enabled?

Comment: @hjpotter92 yes, it is. I have other domains on the same server and there is no problem with mod_rewrite. But on this domain, it doesn't work.

Comment: For starters, combine your first 2 rules so you never redirect to `http:`, like this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.palabi.net [NC,OR] RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on RewriteRule .* https://palabi.net/$0 [L,R=301]`.